# How to Retry @BeforeClass method in testng?

Tags: java, testng

I have a dependency to an external web service in my @BeforeClass method. The dependency keeps timing out. I need to retry this a couple of times.

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    //Call to dependency
}

@Test
public void test() {
    //The actual test
}
```

I use the retryAnalyzer to retry my tests. for eg

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryDecider.class)
public void test() {
    //The actual test
}
```

Is there something similar for @BeforeClass ?

Comment: I assume the code in setup() tries to connect to webservice and gets some response or exception? Can you wrap this code in a for/while loop until OK condition is met or give up after a number of attempts?

Comment: have you thought about mocking the dependency?

Comment: Wrapping this in a loop would work, but I was looking at a preexisting feature like the retryAnalyzer. That way I would not have to worry about writing all setup() methods in a loop.

Comment: @MemLeak since I was looking to write an integration test, mocking is not an option